# Llenar un Input de forma automática con otro Input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo dos `Input`, uno con el número de empleado y otro con el nombre del empleado, lo que quiero hacer es que al escribir el numero del empleado me muestre tambien el nombre en el siguiente input sin recargar la pagina, el código que tengo es el siguientes:

```
<span> Número del Empleado </span> <input type="text" id="numeroE" name="numeroE" onkeyup="buscar();"> <br> <br>
<span> Nombre del Empleado </span> <input type="text" id="nombreE" name="nombreE" disabled> <br> <br>
```

En javascript solo tengo la idea de que puede ser con un `Document.getElementById` de antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Según estiendo estás consultando una base de datos para traer el nombre con el id, ¿cierto? Es muy bueno que compartas todo el código con la consulta sql.

Comment: Tienes razon, deja lo anexo en este comentario
create table alta(
  fecha date,
  turno varchar(30),
  linea varchar(30),
  numEmpleado varchar(50),
  nomEmpleado varchar(50),
  constraint pk_alta primary key (id_alta)
);
  numEmpleado int,
  nomEmpleado varchar(50),
  constraint pk_empleados primary key (numEmpleado)
);

Answer (score 0):

```
function buscar()
{
 $("#nombreE").val($("#numeroE").val());
}
```

En tu evento de onkeyup mandas llamar buscar
En buscar le asignas el valor del 1er input al 2o input.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que pretendes es consultar la base dependiendo de lo se que escriba en un campo sera con ajax ya que necesitas hacer una peticion al servidor, primero hay que mandar el valor del numero asi:

```
<span> Número del Empleado </span> <input type="text" id="numeroE" name="numeroE" onkeyup="buscar(this.value);"> <br> <br>
<span> Nombre del Empleado </span> <input type="text" id="nombreE" name="nombreE" disabled> <br> <br>
```

y tu funcion buscar quedaria algo asi

```
function buscar(numero_empleado) {

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();               
        var numero = "numero="+numero_empleado;
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("nombreE").value = this.responseText;
            }       
          };
        xhttp.open("POST", "empleado.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        xhttp.send(numero);
}
```

donde empleado.php es un archivo donde haces tu consulta a la base y regresa el nombre del empleado dependiendo del numero que le mandas por POST

Answer (score -1):

Necesariamente otro input? es la salida de los datos. Cree este ejemplo recibiendo el dato en un input y mostrándolo en etiqueta. Lo que buscas no necesita refrescar la web, así que realizo una petición ajax, luego envío lo tecleado en el input al svr  y realizo la consulta con el id convirtiendo a un JSON. Luego la envió nuevamente al cliente conviertiendola a string y y por medio de un for.Each tomo el nombre y lo muestro donde quiera (html).

BD: Empleado
tabla: empleado

Espero sea lo que busques y te pueda ayudar (Y)
Js: empleado.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id').keyup(function(){

        let id = $('#id').val();

        $.ajax({
            url:'consultEmpleado.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {id},
            success: function(response){
                let string = JSON.parse(response);
                let plantilla = ' ';

                string.forEach(emple =>{
                    plantilla +=`
                    <li>${emple.nombre}</li>
                    `           
                });
                $('#empleado').html(plantilla);
                console.log(plantilla);
            }

        })


    });
});
```

php: Consulta empleado

```
<?php
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("svr", "usser","pass", "tubasededatos");
    if(!$conexion){
        echo 'Error de conexion a Base de datos';
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM Empleados WHERE id = '$id'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

        if (!$resultado) {
            die('error en la consulta gonorrea!');
        }

        $json = array();
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
            $json[] = array(

                'id' => $row['id'],
                'nombre' => $row['nombre']
            );
        }
        $jsonString = json_encode($json);
        echo $jsonString;
    }
  ?>
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="empleado.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <style>

        input,div{

            border: 1px solid black; 
            width:200px; 
            height: 35px; 
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

        <p>ID</p>
        <input type="text" id="id" > 
        <p>EMPLEADO</p>
        <div id="empleado"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aca tambien haces los mismo. Copias y pegas. No tiene argumento la respuesta